# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil while using "gpuImage" with "javacv" in android

Tags: java, android, javacv, android-gpuimageview, android-ffmpeg

I want to use both `javacv` and `gpuimage`in my android application. Everything works fine if i only include `javacv` in my app. When i include `gpuimage` in my app, it crashes and shows this message.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.<clinit>(avcodec.java:1650)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<init>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:149)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder.<init>(FFmpegFrameRecorder.java:126)
    at com.example.app.ShareActivity.initRecorder(ShareActivity.java:351)
    at com.example.app.ShareActivity.access$1000(ShareActivity.java:49)
    at com.example.app.ShareActivity$8.run(ShareActivity.java:398)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This my `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'org.bytedeco:javacv:1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.18'
}
```

i extracted `ffmpeg-android-arm.jar` and kept all `*.so` files inside `app\src\jniLibs\armeabi`. App works properly without `gpuimage`.

Comment: The *.so files could have been build on different version of NDK with the current NDK you are having in your project.

Comment: @autobot_101ok, so how can i solve this problem? please suggest any solution for that.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem... anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
compile 'org.bytedeco:javacv:1.1'
```

from your Gradle and add the lines below

```
compile(group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv-platform', version: '1.3'){
    exclude group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets'
}
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '3.2.1-1.3'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '3.2.1-1.3', classifier: 'android-arm'
```